# Mongo can't start service

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I have Ubuntu 16.04. And reinstall mongobd following tutorial  on oficial mongo site - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
As result i have:
mongo -version

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.5
git version: 3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

But I cant start mongodb((

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-22 16:27:13 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 29736 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 29736 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 22 16:27:13 mahumachinen systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Jan 22 16:27:13 mahumachinen systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 22 16:27:13 mahumachinen systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 22 16:27:13 mahumachinen systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Please help!

Comment: One thing that stands out to me is that you are referring to `mongodb.service`, but if you followed the instructions you linked, the service is actually `mongod.service`.  You might be able to figure out the cause of the service failure in `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` (unless you changed the logging path in `/etc/mongod.conf`).

Comment: Thank you, probably i made somewhere mistake, I made several instalations from different tuturials.
now  /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log is empty. 
although
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: $ sudo service mongod start
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
$ sudo systemctl unmask mongodb
$ sudo service mongod start

Comment: sudo service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-22 17:19:43 UTC; 6s ago

Comment: sudo /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf helps me. Thank you, but whats happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue by setting the wrong ownership on the folder `/var/log/mongodb`:

```
root@demo:~# ls -lh /var/log/mongodb/
total 512
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 22 17:57 mongod.log
root@demo:~# systemctl restart mongod
root@demo:~# systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-22 17:57:13 UTC; 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 795 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 795 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 22 17:57:13 demo systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jan 22 17:57:13 demo systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 22 17:57:13 demo systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 22 17:57:13 demo systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Try correcting the ownership of the MongoDB logging and data directories:

```
root@demo:~# chown -Rc mongodb. /var/log/mongodb
changed ownership of '/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log' from root:root to mongodb:nogroup
changed ownership of '/var/log/mongodb' from root:root to mongodb:nogroup
root@demo:~# chown -Rc mongodb. /var/lib/mongodb
root@demo:~# systemctl restart mongod
root@demo:~# systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-01-22 17:58:30 UTC; 1s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 802 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─802 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

Jan 22 17:58:30 demo systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
```

If this doesn't work, try reinstalling MongoDB, deleting all existing data:

```
sudo apt purge mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
sudo rm -rfv /etc/mongod.conf /var/log/mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo find /tmp -type s -iname '*mongodb*' -delete
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

Comment: Tried correcting the ownership of the MongoDB logging and data directories, but it did not help, reinstalled, but also did not help.

Comment: Now again  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-22 18:45:00 UTC; 7s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 31469 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 31469 (code=exited, status=100)

Comment: @ViktorKushnir: What's the log file showing now?

Comment: log file is empty now

Comment: After reinstall:
$ sudo systemctl start mongod
 Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

Comment: @ViktorKushnir: I do not see how this is possible if you're following [the installation instructions in the official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).  The `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` file comes from the `mongodb-org-server` package.

Comment: Yes, its very strange(((

Comment: hi! Please I need your help! I stiil have a problem with mongo(( Finally I have the same story like here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691032/mongod-service-start-exits-with-code-100 But all answers dont helps me.

Comment: @ViktorKushnir: Run `sudo -u mongodb strace -vfts1000 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` and paste as much output as you can to a pastebin (such as [Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/)) starting from the beginning.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FaR6xU49

Comment: $ /usr/bin/mongod --verbose --config /etc/mongod.conf &
[1] 28904
$ 2019-01-23T16:10:36.190+0000 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"

Comment: $ ls -la /var/log/ | grep mongo
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb  mongodb     4096 Jan 23 15:34 mongodb

Comment: @ViktorKushnir: Remove the file `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`, which currently has the wrong permissions.  That's what the `strace` indicates is the "Fatal Assertion".

Comment: Man, you are great! Although I tried it before, but now it worked! Thank you more!!!

Comment: @ViktorKushnir: I updated the answer to include removing the socket.  If you're good to go, please check the [gray check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUUGu.png) by my answer to indicate that you accepted it.

Comment: I marked the check, but cant vote(( - http://prntscr.com/mb5ydf

Comment: Thank You so much. I have tried all the stuff that I can do and find but this is the last post which just helped me.

Comment: reinstalling MongoDB solved my issue. After reinstalling should I apply `sudo chown -Rc mongodb. /var/lib/mongodb`?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't need to.  I don't expect it to hurt if you do the `chown`.